# Python Remove From List of Times Based on Business Hours

Tags: python, django

I have a tuple list of times in 15 min intervals for 24h range. Now I need to remove times outside of business hours.

My times:

```
times = []
for i in range(0, 24 * 4):
    times.append((datetime.combine(date.today(), time()) + timedelta(minutes=15) * i).time())
```

Business Hours:

```
time_open = '08:00:00'
time_close = '17:00:00'
```

How do I remove times from the list outside of the business hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution if i understood what you want. You can just check if the time is between the hours the business is open / closed before appending to the list.

```
from datetime import datetime as d, timedelta, time
import datetime as o_d

time_open = '08:00:00'
time_close = '17:00:00'
times = []
for i in range(0, 24 * 4):
    date = (d.combine(o_d.date.today(), time()) + timedelta(minutes=15) * i).time()
    date_str = date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if time_open <= date_str <= time_close:
        times.append(date_str)
        #times.append(date)
print(times)
```

**Edit from comments:** If you wanted a tuple representation of what's typically called "military" time vs what most people are used to i.e. - AM / PM you can do the following

```
from datetime import datetime as d, timedelta, time
import datetime as o_d

time_open = '08:00:00'
time_close = '17:00:00'
times = []
for i in range(0, 24 * 4):
    date = (d.combine(o_d.date.today(), time()) + timedelta(minutes=15) * i).time()
    date_str = date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if time_open <= date_str <= time_close:

        #If you want a list of just standard times
        #times.append(date_str)

        #If you want the time representation(s) here and no longer need the 
        #the datetime object

        times.append((date_str, date.strftime("%I:%M %p"))

        #If you still need the datetime object append this do list comprehension below in comment with #options = ....
        #times.append(date)
print(times)

#assuming you have appended date above see comment
#options = [( c.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), c.strftime("%I:%M %p")) for c in times]
```

Comment: Thank for the help! I'm getting `'module' object has no attribute 'combine'` error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW my tuple list is now giving me an error. Any suggestions? `options=[( choice.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), choice.strftime("%I:%M %p")) for choice in times]
`

Comment: `strftime` makes `date_str` a string you cant call strftime again on a string object. You can append `times.append(date)` instead of `date_str` and do your list comprehension and it will work.

Comment: Can you update your respond please? I'm not sure if I'm following. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: in what format is your time data? mine is in a panda frame and not sure if i need to transform it to something else..